# Changing the colour of JTable cell border on starting editing (not on click, only when cursor appears)

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to change the border of a JTable cell on starting of editing, as in: when the text cursor appears. How would you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that purposes you can write your own [`TableCellEditor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html) or use `DefaultTableCellEditor`.

With second way you can do it with this code (`table` is your table):

```
for(int i =0;i<table.getColumnCount();i++){
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellEditor(getCellEditor());
}
```

and code of `getCellEditor()` method:

```
private TableCellEditor getCellEditor() {
    JTextField f = new JTextField();
    f.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
    return new DefaultCellEditor(f);
}
```

Here I use `DefaultCellEditor` with `JTextField` which has red border.

I think it helps you.

Comment: what do you mean by 'use' DefaultTableCellEditor?

Comment: It is editor class  for table colum which edit your value  , watch my example. Set that editor for columns of your table. This class provides with default java.

Comment: So I create a class extending the `DefaultTableCellEditor` and override `getCellEditor` method, and then in the `main` method I put this loop? Or where is this loop being put?

Comment: Loop? For what ? Do you try my example?! It do all what you need. Check getCellEditor method in my answer it returns DefaultTableCellEditor  that you need, set it to column . You needn' t any subclass . If you about loop in my answer it set editor to all columns of your table , put it after you create your table

Comment: Well there is a for loop in your answer :) I see now, it works! I thought it would involve overriding some default editor methods, you answer is actually really simple, thanks!

Comment: This approach can potentially lose some default functionality. For example, by default, an Integer editor will display a Black border when editing starts and then display a Red border if a non numeric value is entered. With this approach you are creating a new editor with no default functionality which is probably ok for simple text cells, but not for cells with other data types.

Comment: @camickr Really? where i can read about this behavior? I can't repety it(

Comment: The behaviour isn't documented anywhere (that I know of), but you can read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concepts: Renderers and Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and try the `TableDemo` example to see this functionality demonstrated.

Comment: @camickr really , but for that behavior `JTable` use `JTable.NumberEditor` class which is invisible((. because of that, I think for customizing editor `DefaultCellEditor` is suitable, also you can add some validations, if you want.